# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n^2$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_nb_n|$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges, so does $\sum^{\infty}b_n^2$. **Prove that $\sum^{\infty}|a_n\cdot b_n|$ converges.**

I don't know how to use the information I am given in the hypothesis to make any conclussion.

What I know:

(1) $\sum^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges $\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$

Same for $b_n$:

$\sum^{\infty}b_n^2$ converges $\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = 0$

Then:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n\cdot b_n|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|\cdot |b_n|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}|b_n|=0$

Which doesn't help because (1) is a one-way implication.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you use the first two partial sums to find a bound on the third partial sum?

Comment: You may use comparison test together with either $$|a_n b_n| \leq \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2 + b_n^2)$$ or $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} |a_n b_n| \leq \sqrt{\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n^2 \right)\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n^2 \right)}. $$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

By [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_nb_n|\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n^2}$$

Comment: Is this really a hint? It feels more like a solution.

Comment: @fauxefox Yes I've maybe I've given too much information fo a hint but once we suggest CS it is difficult to do not lead almost to the solution.